# Blocking an ip with netsh

Tags: firewall, url, netsh

I know that `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="name" dir=out remoteip=%IP% protocol=TCP action=block`
blocks the IP, and we can find the IP by simply pinging it.

I used to use it to block a game's chat region and it still works. However, it doesn't block the access to any website, how do I block a website with `netsh`?

Additionally, sometimes the IP of a website changes frequently why is that?

Answer (score 1):

> sometimes the ip of a website changes frequently why is that?

This can come because of :

- The website doesn't have a static IP from its ISP
- The website is stored on or has a front-end of more than one computer,
  especially if it uses a
  [content distribution network (CDN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)

> how do I block a website with netsh

You don't. The firewall knows how to block IPs and programs, but not
DNS domains.

This is usually done via browser extensions and by security software,
which are better adapted for blocking by DNS.